# Moving community of GIS tool to GIS Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

At FAO in the openForis initiative we build a tool called SEPAL : It's is a cloud computing platform for geographical data processing. It enables users to quickly process large amount of data without high network bandwidth requirements or need to invest in high-performance computing infrastructure.

The source code is available on GitHub : https://github.com/openforis/sepal
The website is open access : https://sepal.io

For several years now we work with many countries toward improving remote sensing monitoring of forests.

Our community was living and asking  question on a private forum and a google Group. Both these community are closed intellectual silos and we would like to better integrate to the open-source community.

To this purpose we would like to move our community to the GIS Stack Exchange. This would allow the Q&A to be moderated and finally referenced in Google search (widening the audience of the tool).

I recently created a new tag for [sepal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sepal).

My first question ([Create a combined Landsat and Sentinel mosaic using SEPAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388332)) has been closed but I felt it was a legitimate question, and the answer provided by my colleague seems legitimate as well.

Are all the questions related to this tag likely to be closed as well?

Is it OK for you to increase the number of toolS included in GIS SE ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion GIS SE should be (or better "is") a platform for all GIS related questions, not depending on which GIS related product or what the community background of a question is. It also does not matter whether the product is open source or commercial. The only thing one should state at this point: GIS SE will never be an **official** support forum for any GIS product or specific GIS software related questions.

So in short: I welcome your initiative by creating a new tag and am looking forward to a wider variety of knowledge-sharing.

Answer (score 8):

When introducing users of your tool to the GIS Stack Exchange read carefully the section of its Help Center titled [Can I support my product on this site?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) which starts:

> We get a lot of requests from product teams about how they can use
> Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange to support their
> communities. Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange works
> really well for technical support and we welcome this, *within limits*.
> If you follow a few simple guidelines then you, your users, and
> Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange can all benefit.

I think it is important that your users are made aware that GIS SE is a site for focused Q&A, and that it is not a discussion forum. I welcome their participation.